# MySQL RDS error logs import for customized alerts

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a requirement wherein I need to migrate my on premise MySQL databases to MySQL RDS instances. Currenty we have scipts that gather data from MySQL error logs to send out alerts. We plan to deploy these scripts on a centralised server from where it should query every RDS instances error log. But I am unable to load the error log in MySQL tables. Is there any way I can automate the process of retrieving the error logs from MySQL RDS instances to my centralised server?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Amazon RDS MySQL DB instances to publish log data to a log group in [Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html). From here you can set up alarms and notification on specific events using [search patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html) or use [subscriptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html) to get access to a real-time feed of log events from CloudWatch Logs and have it delivered to other services such as an Amazon Kinesis stream, Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose stream, or AWS Lambda for custom processing, analysis, or loading to other systems.

If you still want to use a centralized server and parsing each logs through your previous scripts, you can [export your log data from CloudWatch to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3Export.html).